# How can I get constant of integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

When using `Integrate`, *Mathematica* sets a constant of integration automatically. But sometimes we are given that constant already and it should be used in order to get the correct answer. How to manually set that constant?

Comment: Using a **definite** integral instead of an indefinite one will take care of the constant of integration. Remember that $\int_a^a f(x)\mathrm dx=0$.

Comment: Maybe you could give us the details of the problem you are working on. That would make it easier to answer your question more exhaustively.

Comment: In general you can use `DSolve[{y'[x] == f[x], cond}, y[x], x]`, where `cond` is something like `y[2] == 4` or `y'[4] == 0`

Comment: @Coolwater That is what I want to ask! Thanks a lot! This is the first time I raise a question in English. It might be hard to understand. Thank you for your help!